# why token bucket algorithm is better than leak bucket algorithm?

Tags: congestion, policing

I am trying to clear up concept here. This is regarding shaper using Token bucket algorithm.

Let’s assume that the bucket depth is 1500 bytes. And assume that the data rate is 2Bps (very slow one). This means that unless the bucket doesn't have tokens unlike leaky bucket, the data will not be transmitted.
This implies that there will be a delay/drop in the packet transmission. If so, then don’t you think that this will add congestion in the traffic? Imagine, a synchronous communication, where the receiver will time out and ask for re-transmission.
Thus, there will be a lot of packets in the network. So, don’t you think that leaky bucket is better than token bucket?  At least you don’t have a possibility of duplicate packets in leaky bucket. Only disadvantage of leaky bucket is that it will transmit the data always with a constant bit rate. 
So, it will throttle the bit rate to a lower value even when the source is sending at a higher bit rate.

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand what you are getting at.  At 2Bps you will likely have re-transmission regardless if you re using a token bucket or leaky bucket as you will hit timeouts on the end hosts before your bucket has transmitted your first packets.

Comment: You pitch the constant bit rate of the leaky bucket as a disadvantage while for most this is the advantage. If you don't want that behaviour you can pick a different algorithm.